# Issue in displaying Decimal fields in SSRS with mdx Query

Tags: ssas, reporting-services

We are facing issue while displying the amount in ssrs reports which makes use of mdx query.
For Example : this value is retured by mdx query 278.25 but when it is binded with ssrs it shows 27.825,00.
We are using culture de-DE(German) in report.

We have tried the following solutions but still the issue remains in SSRS report:
From mdx side We have tried FORMAT_STRING = "#0,00" function for displying numeric value.
From report side we have tried to use replace function to replace '.' with ',', but its not working fine.

Sample Query can be found below

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[CumEGTKDAmount] AS sum({[Time].[Month].FIRSTCHILD: [Time].[Month].CurrentMember},[Measures].[EGTKD] * [Measures].[AvgStockPrice])
SELECT
    {
        [Measures].[CumEGTKDAmount]
    } ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY {
                topcount(
                (                
                STRTOSET("[Dim Item].[ItemHierarchy].[Item No].&[00001133]")
                )
            ,50,[Measures].[ReklaQuote])
                } ON ROWS
FROM [QM]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=Replace(Format(Fields!YourFieldName.Value, "#,###0.00"),",",".")
```